Interpretation of Trace Route
I am relatively new to the world of networking. My issue is that I am having a difficult time in making sense out of having private IP addresses in a trace route. Aren't private addresses non-routable? This is a table from my iPhone without being tethered. Presumably my IP address of 192.0.0.2 would be on hop number one? I am unable to upload the pictures, so I describe below. Starting with 72, these look typical.
hop1: empty
hop2: empty
hop3: empty
hop4: empty
hop5: empty
hop6: 10.177.87.92
hop7: another 10 address
hop8: another 10 address
hop9: another 10 address
hop10: another 10 address
hop11: empty
hop12: empty
hop13: 72.14.218.86 
hop14: same as above
hop15: 142
hop16: 142
hop17: 8.8.8.8

For some reason, I am unable to utilize security trails for any reverse lookups.

I know for coaxial cable/fiber ISP's often employ a method of routing that utilizes private IPs. So this may be legitimate. Thanks for reformatting.


Presumably my IP address of 192.0.0.2 would be on hop number one?

Hops represent routers; the first hop isn't your IP address, it's your router. When it comes to generating traceroute responses, each router can choose to respond from whichever IP address it has (since the probe packets don't call for a specific one).
But your 192.0.0.2 is a kind of "super-private" address – it's not meant to ever show up on the wire, and acts more of just a stand-in for DS-Lite IPv6 translation, which adds quite a bit of complexity to everything.
Specifically, the usage of DS-Lite by your ISP means your IPv4 packets actually get converted to IPv6 packets at hop 1 – and then back to IPv4 somewhere around hop 5-6 – and those initial few hops may be purely IPv6 routers that won't necessarily have any IPv4 address that they could respond from; hence the empty hops. (Or, more likely, they are responding from their IPv6 address, but your DS-Lite AFTR is unable to translate it to any IPv4 address.)

Aren't private addresses non-routable?

Private addresses are routable in general – what makes people call them "non-routable" is specifically that Internet operators will not accept routes for such addresses between each other (and of course the fact that private addresses get re-used at hundreds of different places, as is their purpose, so it just wouldn't make sense to route them over Internet).
But as long as you don't need to cross a single operator's boundary (in the typical Internet case), large networks with multiple hops can be built entirely out of private addressing (or a mix of global and private). Every large corporation, university, etc. has such a network, and it's fairly normal to see multiple routing hops consisting of private addresses.
More importantly though, what you're looking at is the source address. It has very little impact on routability; packet routing is based almost entirely on the destination, whereas the source address is only subject to occasional anti-spoofing filters (if at all).
(Reminder of how traceroute works: It doesn't know the path upfront and doesn't send anything to those addresses directly – it only probes "hop 2 towards 8.8.8.8", "hop 4 towards 8.8.8.8", etc. and shows you where the probe replies came from.)
So if the packet actually had a private address as the destination address, then it indeed would not be able to find its destination across the Internet, but your trace doesn't imply that this is the case. If the more-distant responses come from other network operators, then they were sent to your global address (as that's what the distant networks see) – it doesn't really matter what address they were sent from.
(After all, those packets themselves are a "final reply" and aren't really expecting a reply from you again, so it doesn't matter if their source address is unusable.)

How useful is a trace route then? What can and can't it tell us?

It's mildly useful, but it can never tell you absolutely everything. IP is a network that often runs on top of other networks (what is often called "L3 and L2"), and a traceroute only shows you IP hops but not those of the networks underneath.
This was true in the ARPANET era (with IP-over-ARPANET or IP-over-X.25 being blind to the intermediate IMPs or packet switches) and is still true in the modern era (with things like Ethernet switches being invisible to IP).
For example, a country-wide ISP network may be built out of IP routers connected directly (in which case a traceroute would see the entire path hop-by-hop), or it may be built out of Ethernet switches/rbridges, or it may be built out of MPLS switches, with IP only at the border (which would be completely invisible; the IP packet enters the network and pops out somewhere other end of the country in just 1 traceroute hop).
There are also several other things that cause problems with traceroute with the way it "works", but.
So the few things a traceroute can tell you – and then, sometimes with guessing to fill in gaps – are 1) boundaries between network operators – packet went through operator A, then operator C, then operator E, until it reached the destination; 2) rough latency measurement (and even that is often obfuscated by MPLS). A few other things cannot be seen from a single trace, but can only be inferred from comparing a current trace with one you remember from earlier (i.e. not "this looks weird" but rather "this looks a different kind of weird than it usually does")

It will take time to digest what you are saying. How useful is a trace route then? What can and can't it tell us?
What prompted this is that when I do a nslookup, I don't get an authoritative answer I would expect. I get the ipv6 DNS server that I am using instead. Also, my security software claims that it can't get an internet connection. And another software says that my system has been tampered with.  I can't use security trails.com since it give an error message on any lookup. And so many other strange things have occurred that may not be quirks.


Traceroute is getting a bit less useful than it used to be, with the amount of "behind the curtain" networking like MPLS and other L2 virtualization going on (e.g. my work ISP runs a very traditional network overall, but we reach them through a "L2 VPN" connection provisioned through another ISP – it looks like we have a direct fiber connection to our ISP, with them showing up as hop 2, but in reality it goes through some 4–7 hidden hops before it gets there). It still gives you some information, of course, but you have to keep in mind that all kinds of weird things are done these days.



The nslookup result is completely normal – your computer never talks directly to authoritative servers (i.e. the ones actually hosting DNS data; nslookup doesn't even know how to find the right authoritative server for a given domain), it always talks to a DNS cache, and "non-authoritative answer" is exactly what every DNS cache server is going to give you. The only time you won't see that message is if you manually told nslookup to talk to the auth. servers for that specific domain (e.g. nslookup land.nullroute.lt 31.220.42.129).


And, I don't know about your security software, but securitytrails.com is just broken in general, at least when it comes to querying IP addresses.

Thanks for taking the time to provide such thorough answers. This helps a lot!
As far as the nslookup, following several examples, either in interactive or non-interactive mode, I should get under the 'authoritative' part the DNS server that I am using if I do: nslookup google.com, or I should get the DNS server  specified if I do nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8. But I don't.
Invariably, I get a local link address of fe80::10a2:d3ff:fee1:f764 for the server while the address  gives the same of course with port 53.
